# Estimator of variance of an estimator

Tags: statistics

Firts of all, sorry of the title is confusing. The question is this:

Let $X$ be a sample of Bin$(n,p)$, then the estimator $P = \frac{X}{n}$ is unbiased for $p$. Study the estimator $\frac{P(1-P)}{n}$, which is used to estimate the variance of $P$ (Show if it is unbiased and if not, compute its bias)

My solution is this: let $k = \frac{P(1-P)}{n}$. We know that $V(P) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$, so the formula for bias$(k)$ leads me to $\frac{E(P) - E(P^2) - p(1-p)}{n}$. Now I am inclined to use the formula $V(P) = E(P^2) - (E(P))^2$ to find $E(P^2)$. Is my work so far correct, and if it is, can I use the latter formula to continue my calculation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$It looks right so far. Yes, you can use that to find $\E\left[P^2\right]$. To do so, rewrite it as $$\E\left[P^2\right] = \Var(P) + \left(\E[P]\right)^2$$
and substitute in what you know for $\Var(P)$ and $\E[P]$.

Comment: Thank you, 1+2+3+... by Ramanujan summation